# How to detect classifier curve in non-separable SVM problem

Tags: classification, svm, kernel-trick, nonlinear

Suppose we want to classify two class of data that are non-separable with hyper-plane. So we use kernels to map data to high-dimensional space.

See my codes:

```
set.seed(10111)
x = matrix(rnorm(40), 20, 2)
y = rep(c(-1, 1), c(10, 10))
x[y == 1, ] = x[y == 1, ] + 1

library(kernlab)
svp <- ksvm(x,y,type="C-svc",kernel='vanilladot',C=8.026,cross=3)
plot(x,col=ifelse(y>0,1,2),pch=16)
points(x[SVindex(svp),c(1,2)],col="blue",cex=1.5)
# Extract w and b from the model   
w <- colSums(coef(svp)[[1]] * x[SVindex(svp),])
b <- b(svp)
# Draw the lines
abline(b/w[2],-w[1]/w[2])
abline((b+1)/w[2],-w[1]/w[2],lty=2)
abline((b-1)/w[2],-w[1]/w[2],lty=2)
```

and this is the plot:

[image]

My question is that, how we can (find and ) plot the non-linear curve that separate two class?
Something like the black solid curve in blew picture:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Given that you want to plot the result, I assume you have two dimensional data. The easiest way is to train your model $f(x_1, x_2)$, then use it to predict a dense grid, e.g. $x_1 = 0:0.01:1$ and $x_2 = 0:0.01:1$.

The decision boundary is then the contour $f(x_1, x_2) = 0$ or $|f(x_1, x_2)| \leq \epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$, which you can plot with any plotting library. You can plot the margin in a similar fashion, via the contours $f(x_1, x_2) = \pm 1$.

As you didn't specify a language/platform, I can't give more specific info.

Comment: It might be also helpful to plot the support vector points, or at least make them stand out. The support vectors should be hinting the location of the hyperplane and the margins. Essentially support vectors are "violators" of the hyperplane and can be found between two margins.